# Selenium IDE vs Selenium builder

Tags: html, json, selenium

I want to know what's the difference between Selenium IDE and Selenium builder.
All I know it's Selenium builder can support webdriver.

But what is a webdriver?

Thanks

Comment: You should google this question to find the answer. This is not a programming question and is not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 3):

From the Selenium IDE website

> Selenium IDE is an integrated development environment for Selenium scripts. It is implemented as a Firefox extension, and allows you to record, edit, and debug tests. Selenium IDE includes the entire Selenium Core, allowing you to easily and quickly record and play back tests in the actual environment that they will run in.

On the other hand, Builder is an extension that helps you build Selenium tests more quickly by helping turn your actions into Selenium code.

Finally a webdriver is a web automation framework that allows you to execute your tests against different browsers. Selenium-webdriver is one example, but Watir-webdriver is another. These frameworks spin up a browser instance and mimic user action against the page's elements in order to test webpages and webapps.

Answer (score 0):

'Selenium Web Driver' is a tool for writing automated tests of websites. It aims to mimic the behavior of a real user, and as such interacts with the HTML of the application.